# Atalasoft ocr: how to make text in image more readable c#

Tags: c#, console-application, ocr

I'm developing a Console application.

The functionality of the application is user will scan and dump documents into a folder(scanning quality is not good) then I'm using atalasoft dynamic skew to make image properly align and then reading text from the image using tesseract 5.2 but the problem is the quality of the document is not good hence it is not able to read text properly.

What should I do in atalasoft to make my image more readable.